# Valid to add null to listOfNotNull()?

Tags: kotlin

I've read following:

```
listOfNotNull(
    if (isSomeCondition) {
        ListSomeItem(123)
    } else null
)
```

Creating listOfNotNull() with a null in it? Is this valid?

Comment: yes, valid and that's the purpose of it... you may also like to use something as follows in such cases: `listOfNotNull(ListSomeItem(123).takeIf { isSomeCondition })`, usually then, when the condition deals with what has to be added in some way, e.g. `listOfNotNull(firstName.takeIf(String::isNotBlank), surname.takeIf(String::isNotBlank)).joinToString(" ")` (not the best example, as in this way you also could just filter them out...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your condition `isSomeCondition` is false the list will not insert the null value and it will be empty

Check this example

```
val list = listOfNotNull(null)
print(list.size)
```

The output will be zero

And in this example

```
val list = listOfNotNull(null, null, 1, null)
print(list.size)
```

Only 1 will be inserted and the size will be 1

Basically, `listOfNotNull` will filter the values and create a list from the non nulls values

The source code of listOfNotNull

```
public fun <T : Any> listOfNotNull(vararg elements: T?): List<T> = elements.filterNotNull()
```

So your code will be like insert or be empty